# Microsoft Excel change date language

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, date

I have an Excel file which checks the date in a specific value and formats it as "mmm-yy". The problem is that I'm in Spain and for the formula to work I need to change manually to "mmm-aa". I want to avoid this step. I got my computer language set to English and the Excel itself is in English, I don't know why it is taking "aa" instead of "yy"
PD: I'm using a Mac computer

Comment: does aa spanish means yy in English?

Comment: yes! I still haven't figured a way to get around this.

Comment: seems like Microsoft said ["NO"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mobile-mso_2013_release/change-excel-formula-language/d6bf1b1a-5df0-4140-93c0-f2632c65aaa0). and my other useful link is [link1](https://www.excel-function-translation.com/) [link2](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) [link3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/excel-formula-language/2d4ef11c-3480-45b8-8085-ca5c3759b5a2) .

Comment: (link3 said the source of the problem is not in excel, It's in the Windows setting.) Have a try.. ( :

Comment: I'm working on Mac, but I think the problem goes in that direction. Thanks!

Comment: if it solves, you may share the answer in the answer post for the benefit of future readers. ( :